# array length in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I'm getting this error from the line of code below:

> Error: AddIMRConroller Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST at line 21 column 23

```
string[] str1 = imrTable.split('\r\n');
    System.debug( str1.length);
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Salesforce we need to use `size()` method instead of the `length` property. This is something different then Java.